# How to handle template (layouts) inheritance in Jekyll?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, jekyll

I want to have a template "_layouts/template1.html" extend (Django-style) a template _layouts/default.html.

I'm putting this as a YAML front matter in _layouts/template1.html

```
---
layout: default 
---
{{page.content}}
```

but apparently it doesn't work the way I'd like it to work (all the additional markup that is present in template1.html but IS NOT in default.html does not render). It looks like the file that uses template1 layout purely extends default.html.

Is there any way to have layouts inheritance in Jekyll?

Answer (score 11):

What you mean is simply `{{ content }}`.

Yes, layouts can be *piped*.  In your case, if a page uses *template1* layout, it is the *content* for *template1*.  Then, the result of *template1*  is the *content* for *default*.

Answer (score 6):

Jekyll's Liquid templates extend pretty easily, you just have to be sure you're **extending** and not *overwriting* your desired template.

You may actually want to extend page and not default.

So, in your template Front Matter:

```
---
layout:page
---
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the Liquid Inheritance Gem: https://github.com/danwrong/liquid-inheritance

Reference: http://www.sameratiani.com/2011/10/22/get-jekyll-working-with-liquid-inheritance.html

Comment: It looks like this functionality is included in Jekyll now

Comment: Nevermind, I misunderstood how django inheritance works. Still, I think @jdh8's answer with native jekyll templates is most relevant to this question.

Answer (score 0):

`template1.html` from your example will extend `default.html` as long as the latter contains a `{{ content }}` block. See [here](https://github.com/pkazmierczak/pkazmierczak.github.com/blob/octopress-source/source/_layouts/page.html) for example. What it won't do is it won't overwrite anything that `default.html` already contains. For that you'll need the Liquid Inheritance Gem, as mentioned by @juddlyon.